# Embedded Linux Project on Qualcomm Snapdragon S2 (MSM8655)

Tags: embedded, linux, soc

I have my old blackberry 9900 device, I am interested to start a project of modifying and installing linux inside.

To do so I need user manual of the processor (which is turning out hard to find) even with well supported Snapdragon family.

Question: Assuming the SoC doesn't have a memory controller, will it still be theoretically possible to install linux inside it?

Comment: are you aware that you will have to deal with device drivers that are often kept proprietary.

Comment: This is a *very* ambitious thing to do, not a "small project".

Comment: @EugeneSh. as long as i can use the UART output of the linux booting, i would be happy. I am not looking to go on doing device drivers. I wont be needing the device driver for UART protocol.

Comment: @JhonnyS yes i am aware, i want to keep it small by locating boot MMC and flashing the uboot + linux image with custom tool.

Comment: Seems like this SoC was used in the Android [Samsung Galaxy Reverb](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_reverb_m950-4953.php). A quick grep of the kernel source doesn't show anything related though, but it might've been dropped as I'm looking at 5.4 sources. Also, what do you mean by memory controller? It _must_ have a memory controller to use RAM. And looking at Android versions supported and that it supports the ARMv7 ISA I'm pretty sure it has MMU too.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER making it boot and do UART *is* a larger project than you seem to think. Also, I've never heard of any public Qualcomm Snapdragon documentation. Be large enough to buy a million chips, and Qualcomm will start negotiating an NDA with you.

Comment: @JanDorniak +1 This is indeed the "answer" I was looking, So its clear that it can run linux (Android is loosely speaking basically java virtualization on top of mostly linux kernel). From where have you grep kernel source?

Comment: I have the repo cloned on my disk so I just run it in terminal :P

Comment: @MarcusMüller I dont have deep pockets yet to buy million chips yet ;) So I guess I will have to do it the hard way, if even that is possible.

Comment: @JanDorniak I am bit confused, which repository are you referring to? Android image of Galaxy Reverb? also if you write what you have written in an answer, Ill accept it.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER the Linux kernel source repository

Comment: @JanDorniak makes so much sense, you were looking for SoC specific code to see if Qualcomm Snapdragon appears ;-)